# Why is it that templates on Wikipedia becomes "Template:I"?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-templates

On this wiktionary page: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:HSK_list_of_Mandarin_words/Advanced_Mandarin#y

There are template usage that renders as `Template:I` instead of the template usage, e.g.

[image]

When we look at the edits and preview, it renders correctly:

[image]

It looks like the page is labelled with the category [`Pages where template include size is exceeded`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Pages_where_template_include_size_is_exceeded).

**How to resolve this and render it correctly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be resolved by replacing the template usage with `[[internal_link]]`, e.g. before:

```
{{l|cmn|掩饰|tr={{l|cmn|掩飾}}, yǎnshì}}
```

After:

```
* [[掩饰]] ([[掩飾]], yǎnshì)
```

Comment: This answer kind of suggests that the template is useless, what is the purpose of the template and why can it be discarded?

Comment: There's a limit on the no. of templates a page can show in wikipedia. So to overcome the limitation, replacing the templates with internal links would work once the page hits the limit =)

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, what is the purpose of the template and why is it not needed?